# Similarity of perceptron criterion and SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, loss-function, perceptron

In the book "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" by Aggarwal there is an exercise 2.10.1:

> Consider the following loss function for training pair $(\overline{X},y)$:
>   $$L=max(0, a -y(\overline{W} \cdot \overline{X}))$$
>   The test instances are predicted as $\hat{y}=sign(\overline{W} \cdot \overline{X})$. A value of $a=0$ corresponds to the perceptron criterion and a value of $a=1$ corresponds to the SVM. Show that any value of $a>0$ leads to the SVM with an unchanged optimal solution when no regularization is used.

I am trying to solve this exercise and from the previous chapters of the book I drew a conclusion that the stochastic update for such a loss function will be $$\overline{W} \Leftarrow \overline{W} + \alpha y \overline{X} [I(y \hat{y} < a)]$$
so it's different from original SVM for cases where $y \hat{y} \in (a,1)$.  For this range, the weights in original SVM will be updated, but for "modified" SVM the wegiths will not be updated. So I don't see a reason why the "modified" SVM (with $a$ instead of $1$) should be equal to the original SVM. How to solve this exercise?

Comment: Just a tip: you might get more and/or better answers for this kind of theoretical questions on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Erwan thanks for a tip